# Need all the help i can get to figure out why mu4e isnt updating for me

Tags: mu4e

in the spirit of Xmas maybe this year ill finally get this working. so ive been trying to get mu4e working for me for a year or so switching between offline imap to mbsybc etc and always it the same old issue. i cant get mu4e to reliably get new messages to show up in my inbox view. this is what i expect to work. i open mu4e, i use `j` > `i` and i get my inbox header view. i know mbsync is working (i call it from within mu4e via

`(setq mu4e-get-mail-command "/usr/bin/mbsync -a")`

and i can see its indexing every X minutes (`[mu4e] Found 500 matching messages`)

the issue is i never get the inbox view to show (auto refresh) the headers and show me the new mail like in every other email application. i try to use `g` sometimes to refresh yet this is hit or miss. sometimes it does show the new mails after `g` and sometimes it dosent.

i can use `C-S-u' to start manually retrieving mail (this opens a buffer that shows the mu4e process working) and that usually fixes the issues and the new mail are presented in the header view.

I would appreciate any help to try and finally debug this. my mu4e config is here if this helps: https://paste.xinu.at/1JZv/

Comment: You gotta type `(mu4e t)` in your init file. I have no idea why. It just worked.